# Shortcut of 'adding an equation' in Word 2016 for laptop

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, equations

In Microsoft Word 2016 for Windows, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> is a shortcut key for adding an equation.

However, there is no separate key for <kbd>*</kbd> on my laptop keyboard.
I have to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to insert '*', yet
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> does not work for adding an equation.

What can I do to add an equation with a shortcut?

Comment: In my Word 2016, it is `alt-=`.

Comment: "Alt + *" shortcut key combination worked for me to open Equation Editor in Word 2019. Thx.

Answer (score 17):

For Microsoft Word (as well as PowerPoint) on Windows, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> to create a new equation at the cursor.

Comment: Interestingly, for me it is `Alt+'+'`, but only the `+` next to the letters, not the one on the numpad. Also, my Windows and keyboard layout are German and it only works in PowerPoint

Answer (score 5):

To create a shortcut for of 'adding an equation' in MS Office Word 2016

1. after getting to **Customize Keyboard** either by:

   - following the step explained in DavidPostill [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1120815/671338)
   - using the shortcut <kbd>ALt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> ,<kbd>T</kbd>
   - <kbd>Right click</kbd> anywhere inside the Ribbon, then press `Customize Ribonne`
2. press **Customize keyboard**
3. then in **Categories** tab chose : `All Commands` (almost at the bottom of the list)
4. and in the **Commands** tab select: `EquationInsert`.
5. insert a short key
6. Apply it using Assign it

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For Mac OS type <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> to add a new equation.

Answer (score 2):

#### What can I do to use shortcut for adding an equation?

You can change the shortcut to a different key combination.

See below for instructions.

---

#### How to Customize Keyboard Shortcuts in Word 2016

> 1. On the File tab, choose Options.
>
>    You see the Word Options dialog box.
> 2. Go to the Customize Ribbon category.
> 3. Click the Customize button (you can find it at the bottom of the dialog box next to the words “Keyboard Shortcuts”).
>
>    You see the Customize Keyboard dialog box, as shown here.
>
>    [image]
> 4. In the Categories list, choose the category with the command to which you want to assign the keyboard shortcut.
>
>    At the bottom of the list are the Macros, Fonts, Building Blocks,
>      Styles, and Common Symbols categories.
> 5. Choose the command name, macro, font, building block, style, or symbol name in the Commands list.
> 6. In the Press New Shortcut Key box, type the keyboard shortcut.
>
>    Press the actual keys. For example, if the shortcut is Ctrl+8, press
>      the Ctrl key and the 8 key — don’t type out C-t-r-l- +8.
>
>    If you try to assign a shortcut that has already been assigned, the
>      words “Currently assigned to” and a command name appear below the
>      Current Keys box. You can override the preassigned keyboard assignment
>      by entering a keyboard assignment of your own.
> 7. If you want the keyboard shortcut changes you make to apply to the document you’re working on, not to all documents created with the
>      template you’re working with, open the Save Changes In drop-down list
>      and choose your document’s name.
> 8. Click the Assign button.
> 9. When you finish assigning keyboard shortcuts, close the Customize Keyboard dialog box.

Source [How to Customize Keyboard Shortcuts in Word 2016](http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/word/how-to-customize-keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-2016/)

Comment: @sinni800 *shrug* - it solves the question asked by the OP.

Answer (score -1):

The shortcuts are the same as they were in Word 2013 (and probably before):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> gives an equation.
 See also <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> for more options. 
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd> gives the same result
as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>.
                      (That's an <kbd>i</kbd>.)

*by the way...*

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> gives a text box.